# How to get text which is inside the span tag using selenium webdriver?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I want to get the text which is inside the span. However, I am not able to achieve it. The text is inside `ul<li<span<a<span`. I am using selenium with python.

[image: This is the structure of the web page. I want to get the text "Canned & Jarred Food."]

Below is the code which I tried:

```
departmentCategoryContent = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('a-list-item')
departmentCategory = departmentCategoryContent.find_elements_by_tag_name('span')
```

after this, I am just iterating departmentCategory and printing the text using `.text` i.e

```
[ print(x.text) for x in departmentCategory ]
```

However, this is generating an error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_tag_name'`.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can get the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

As far as I understand, `departmentCategoryContent` is a list, not a single `WebElement`, then it doesn't have the `find_elements_by_tag_name()` method.

**Solution:**

you can choose 1 of 2 ways below:

1. You need for-each of list `departmentCategoryContent` first, then `find_elements_by_tag_name()`.
2. Save time with one single statement, using `find_elements_by_css_selector()`:

`departmentCategory = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.a-spacing-micro.apb-browse-refinements-indent-2 .a-list-item span')`

`[ print(x.text) for x in departmentCategory ]`

Test on devtool:

[image]

---

**Explanation**:

Your locator `.a-list-item span` will return all the `span` tag belong to the `div` that has class `.a-list-time`. There are 88 items containing the unwanted tags.

[image]

So, you need to add more specific locator to separate  the other div. In this case, I use some more classes. `.a-spacing-micro.apb-browse-refinements-indent-2`

[image]

Comment: I understand the error. But now how am supposed to get the text.

Comment: You can check the second approach that is easier than the first one.

Comment: It is not printing anything.

Comment: Could you provide the link of web page? I want to make sure the locator is correct before print or do something else

Comment: https://www.amazon.in/pantry-cooking-essentials/b/?ie=UTF8&node=9735693031&ref_=sv_pantry_1
I want the content of Department -> Amazon Pantry Cooking Essentials.

Comment: I updated the cssSeletor, you can try that. If it works on dev tool, then it probably works on python code.

Comment: It is working. Can you please explain what you did?

Comment: I updated the answer explaining what I did. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You're looping over the wrong thing. You want to loop through the 'a-list-item' list and find a single span element that is a child of that webElement. Try this:

```
departmentCategoryContent = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('a-list-item')

print(x.find_element_by_tag_name('span').text) for x in departmentCategoryContent
```

note that the second dom search is a find_element (not find_elements) which will return a single webElement, not a list.

Comment: This works just need to add the print statement inside [ ]. There is some extra content in the class 'a-list-item'. I tried to use 'a-color-base a-link-normal' class name to achieve the same but it doesn't print anything.

Comment: If it works, select it as the answer. Sounds like you might still have some work todo on your locators though!

Comment: what do you mean by extra text?

Comment: There are some more elements with the same class name. This works too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Read the latest Documentation, the individual find_by_element***by*** has been deprecated, means not available as attribute, now you have to use By class as it is explained in the documentation.
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html